# JOOQ timestampDiff(field_datetime1, field_datetime2) to set value in an update query not working

Tags: java, mysql, datetime, jooq, timestampdiff

I'm using MYSQL and JOOQ and I'm trying to write an update query.
In this query I want to update `field_datetime1` (type datetime) and also update `field_timedifference`  (type bigint) with the time difference in milliseconds between field_datetime1 and field_datetime2.

How do I achive that with JOOQ?

I tried to write this code:

```
update(table)
.set(field_datetime1, now())
.set(field_timedifference, timestampDiff(field_datetime1, field_datetime2))
```

But it is not compiling, I get this error:

```
Cannot resolve method 'set(org.jooq.TableField<MyRecordType,java.lang.Long>, org.jooq.Field<org.jooq.types.DayToSecond>, org.jooq.TableField<MyRecordType,java.lang.Long>)'
```

I tried to wrap it in DSL.val and it does compile but it sends `null` in the query.

This is the query that I need to run, I tested it on MYSQL workbanch and it is exactly what I need:

```
update myTable 
set field_timedifference = 
TIMESTAMPDIFF(microsecond, field_datetime1, field_datetime2)
```

Answer (score 1):

My coworker investigated and found an easy way to write it:

```
update(table)
.set(field_datetime1, now())
.set(field_timedifference, DSL.field("timestampDiff({0}, {1}, {2})", Long.class,  DSL.keyword(DatePart.MICROSECOND.toSQL()), field_datetime1, field_datetime2))
```

This way jooq generates an actual query in the set :)